# Prolog list combinations

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a prolog code which will take a list and return all pairs of each element of that list. So for example:

```
   X = 1, Y = 2, Zs = [3] ;
   X = 1, Y = 3, Zs = [2] ;
   X = 2, Y = 1, Zs = [3] ;
   X = 2, Y = 3, Zs = [1] ;
   X = 3, Y = 1, Zs = [2] ;
   X = 3, Y = 2, Zs = [3]
```

So far I am able to get uptil the third line and not able to get the rest of the output. My code is:

```
select_pair(X,Y,[X|Xs],Zs):- select(Y,Xs,Zs).
select_pair(X,Y,[H|Z1],[H|Z2]):- select_pair(X,Y,Z1,Z2).
```

Comment: Can you show the sample input which should generate the given output? I don't quite understand what you mean by 'return all pairs of each element'.

Comment: here's one: select_pair(X, Y, [1,2,3], Zs).

Comment: Is the *X = 3, Y = 2, Zs = [3]* example output a typo? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In words, what you want to achieve is:

- Take any X from the input list
- Take any Y different from X from the input list
- Elements other than X and Y are in Zs

This translates quite easily into a prolog predicate:

```
select_pair(X, Y, L, Zs) :-
    select(X, L, Xs),
    select(Y, Xs, Zs).
```

First we select X from the input L. From the remaining elements Xs we select Y. After this, the remaining elements is Zs.